# Spring AOP Generic Typing

Tags: java, spring, aop

I am new to Spring and I am running into a problem with an aspect. The pointcut is an interface that uses generic typing:

```
public interface DaoJdbc<T> {
    public void create(T input);
    public T read(int id);
    public void update(T s);
    public void delete(int id);
    public void getDailyMessage();
}
```

Here is my aspect:

```
<aop:aspect ref="security">
    <aop:pointcut id="passwordNeeded"
        expression="execution(* com.user.service.DaoJdbc.*(..))" />
    <aop:before pointcut-ref="passwordNeeded" method="check" />
</aop:aspect>
```

The aspect will work for `delete()`, but not for `create()`. It will work for 'create()' if I use an implementation of DaoJdbc, instead of the interface itself (which I do not want to do). I can assume this is an issue with the fact that `update()` uses a generic type and `delete()` does not. Is there any way I could get this to work using the interface? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution, a plus sign is needed to indicate a generic.

```
expression="execution(* com.user.service.DaoJdbc+.*(..))"
```