# Spring AOP @AfterReturning not firing/triggering/matching on a method that has collections in the signature

Tags: spring, spring-aop

I have a Spring AOP @AfterReturning advice annotation that is not firing/triggering/matching an execution pointcut on a method that has collections in both the return type and parameters.  I have other simple signature methods in the same target class that I can trigger; therefore I know that I have properly configured Spring. I consulted the [Eclipse AspectJ documentation](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/adk15notebook/generics-inAspectJ5.html#matching-generic-and-parameterized-types-in-pointcut-expressions) that discusses matching and realize the issue is most likely related to handling the type erasure properly.  I tried running the gamut of wild cards to specifying the proper erasure, but still cannot match the signature.

I found these stack overflow posts, but they were not indentical to what I am needing to do here: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20726737/aop-spring-afterreturning-not-working-as-expected), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975294/spring-aop-generic-typing), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131910/pointcut-not-working-for-generic-interface)

Additionally, I do not think I saw anything in the [Spring Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131910/pointcut-not-working-for-generic-interface) explicitly state that what I am trying to do is not supported.  Section 7.2.4.6 does warn about generic collections when used as advice parameters, but I do not see anything that prohibits the use of generic collections when matching in pointcut expressions.

Here is a sanitized example of what I am doing:

**Aspect Interface**

```
package com.myorg;
public interface MyAspect {
    void afterBusinessLogicMethod(Object result);
}
```

**Aspect Impl**

```
package com.myorg;
//imports removed for brevity
@Aspect
@Component
public class MyAspectImpl implements MyAspect {
    @AfterReturning(pointcut="execution(java.util.Map<*,*> com.myorg.a.BusinessLogic.process(java.util.Set<*>,*))",
                 returning="result")
    @Override
    public void afterBusinessLogicMethod(Object result) {
        logger.debug("**** after returning triggered");
    }

}
```

Note that I tried the following wild-carded pointcut expression and many permutations in between:

```
Map<Long, com.myorg.a.MyPojo> process(Set<Long> pojoIds, Boolean fullData)
```

**Targeted Interface**

```
package com.myorg.a;
public interface BusinessLogic {
    Map<Long, MyPojo> process(Set<Long> pojoIds, Boolean enable);
}
```

**Targeted Impl**

```
package com.myorg.a;
@Component
public class BusinessLogicImpl implements BusinessLogic {
    @Override
    public Map<Long, MyPojo> process(Set<Long> pojoIds, Boolean enable) {
        //Omitted for brevity
    }
}
```

Comment: The config and code you posted works for me. Try creating a simple project using just the details you posted and test it.

Comment: @AndreiStefan I created a simple project and the setup does work. Obviously I have some other conflict going on, so I will do some process of elimination.

Comment: @AndreiStefan I ended up moving the target of my pointcut into its own interface/implementation, and that solved the issue, but I don't know why this solved my issue.  At first I thought perhaps it had to do with two methods in the interface having the same param list and return types, but different names.  However, I duplicated that scenario in my test project and it worked there.  I am happy that I got it to work even though I am still scratching my head.